# MySQL 5.5 install conflicting

Tags: mysql, yum

I am trying to install MySQL 5.5 on my CentOS machine, but when running `yum install` I get the following:

```
file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql51-libs-5.1.65-1.ius.el5.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql51-libs-5.1.65-1.ius.el5.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql51-libs-5.1.65-1.ius.el5.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql51-libs-5.1.65-1.ius.el5.x86_64
```

It did have MySQL 5.1 installed, but I thought I had removed it, help much needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove mysql51-libs-5.1.65-1.ius.el5.x86_64

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql51-libs

rpm -e <what you find>
```

Maybe there will be some dependencies, so remove them also before installing new version.

Never mix-up repos.Use official repos only to avaiod such situations.